# How to use Angular 2 lazy loading in Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core Template Pack

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack, asp.net-core

I try to implement router lazy loading in angular 2, so that I can do something like

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full',
 { path: 'about', loadChildren: './+about/about.module#AboutModule' }
];
```

It requires set up like

```
webpack.config.js
loaders: [
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      ‘awesome-typescript-loader’, 
      ‘angular2-template-loader’, 
     ‘angular2-router-loader’]
    },
  ...
]
```

The problem is I am using Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core Template Pack, which got completely different contents in webpack.config.js. How can I set up to make the lazy loading working?

Should I be using ASP.NET Core Template Pack in the long run for developing angular 2 applications? I am not sure whether ASP.NET Core Template Pack is the right path for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be quite simple

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'hero', loadChildren: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(require('./components/hero/hero.module')['HeroModule']);
    } }
```

];

rather than

```
const routes: Routes = [
{  path: 'hero', loadChildren: './components/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
]
```

The idea is coming from http://qiita.com/Quramy/items/e3e6d63a2b155aec2067